# Building SOAP request with suds and Python - XML not being generated properly

Tags: python, xml, soap

Here is the error:

```
No handlers could be found for logger "suds.client"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "bling.py", line 134, in <module>
    get_data("146.215.236.10", list)
  File "bling.py", line 48, in get_data
    retval = client.service.SelectCmDevice("", stuff)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/suds/client.py", line 542, in __call__
    return client.invoke(args, kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/suds/client.py", line 602, in invoke
    result = self.send(soapenv)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/suds/client.py", line 649, in send
    result = self.failed(binding, e)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/suds/client.py", line 702, in failed
    r, p = binding.get_fault(reply)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/suds/bindings/binding.py", line 265, in get_fault
    raise WebFault(p, faultroot)
suds.WebFault: Server raised fault: 'org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: Element type "SelectItem" must be followed by either attribute specifications, ">" or "/>".'
```

Here is the code:

```
def get_data(ip, list):
  """
  Connect to soap webservice
  Append device name and status
  To data list
  """
  stuff = {}
  stuff['SelectBy'] = 'Name'
  count = 0
  for i in list:
    if "SelectItems" not in stuff:
      stuff['SelectItems'] = {}
    if 'SelectItem[' + str(count) + ']' not in stuff['SelectItems']:
      stuff['SelectItems']['SelectItem[' + str(count) + ']'] = {}
    stuff['SelectItems']['SelectItem[' + str(count) + ']']['Item'] = i
    count = count + 1


  t = HttpAuthenticated(**credentials)
  uri = 'https://' + ip + ':8443/realtimeservice/services/RisPort?wsdl'
  imp = Import('http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/')
  doctor = ImportDoctor(imp)
  client = Client(url=uri, transport=t, doctor=doctor)
  retval = client.service.SelectCmDevice("", stuff)
  pprint(retval)
  sys.exit(0)
  for node in retval['SelectCmDeviceResult'].CmNodes:
    for dev in node.CmDevices:
      name   = dev.Name
      status = dev.Status
      data.append([name,status])
```

I am trying to call the Cisco Risport API with Python however even when emulating how it is done in PHP I get an error and I am really trying not to port over to PHP at this point in the project.

Here is how PHP passes the data:

```
foreach ($devices_chunks as $chunk){
    echo '.';

    //Prepare RisPort request
    $array["SelectBy"] = "Name";
    $array["Status"] = "Registered";
    //$array["Class"] = "Phone";
    //$array["MaxReturnedDevices"] = "1000";
    $i = 1;
    foreach($chunk as $device){
        $array["SelectItems"]["SelectItem[$i]"]["Item"] = $device->name;
        $i++;
    }

    // Run RisPost Query + wait a bit as max requests is 15 per min.
    $response = $soap_ris->SelectCmDevice("",$array);
```

I think the problem is with how suds is transposing the dict of dict to XML, any thoughts on how to fix this outside of manually building SOAP XML request?

thanks!